# SQL ORACLE SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have multiple email_id in a column like this:

```
aaaaaa.bbbbb.cccc@xyz.com;mmmm.cccc@xyz.com;ppp.ddd.ssss@xyz.com
sssss.fffff@xyz.com
pppp.gggg@xyz.com;bbbb.kkk.ppp@xyz.com;nnn.ppp@xyz.com
uuuu.vvvvv@xyz.com
```

I want to get first email if they have more than one email id in the column. Each email_id in a column is separated by "`;`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `instr` and `substr`.

```
select case when instr(email,';') > 0 then substr(email,1,instr(email,';')-1) else email end as new_email_col
from tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (email, '([^;]*)') AS first
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo